# I have a couple of images that I'm trying to add a mouseListener to and it doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, imageicon, drawimage

I've been trying to add a mouseListener to an image I drew in paintComponent but it doesn't seem to work. And i tried to make it a JLabel and add the mouseListener but it did not work either. The only solution that I was able to find is that I would add the mouseListener to the paintComponent class itself and I have several images drawn there and each image when clicked should fire an mousePressed event. 
I tried to draw each image in a different JPanel then add those to a JPanel in the JFrame but they override each other. 
Here's an example of one of the 3 Images and how I inilized them:

```
    ImageIcon emirates = new ImageIcon("UAE.png");
    Image uae = emirates.getImage();
```

and here's my paintComponent class that's implemented in the no-arg consutructed of the JFrame class.

```
class Map extends JPanel{

int x = getWidth()/2;
int y = getHeight()/2;

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(uae,(x+480), (y+265),100,100,this);
    g.drawImage(bhr, (x+420), (y+240),50,50,this);
    g.drawImage(kwt,(x+350), (y+150),80,80,this);

}

}
```

As you can see I have multiple maps to be drawn. But I can only one mouseListener to the whole class. What should I do?

Comment: Bascailly i'm constructing a map and when the user clicks the map of a the current county, a new window will appear with the information.

Comment: `And i tried to make it a JLabel and add the mouseListener but it did not work either.` - well it should work, so the problem is with your code. Since you didn't post your code I'm not sure how you expect us to help.  Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `but they override each other`: you need to add a new mouseListener to each `JLabel`. (Alternatively you need to identify the  source (the specific label) of the mouse click, and use it to respond properly)